# Clipping results in a black (empty value) raster althoug having the same CRS

Tags: qgis, clip

I use QGIS 2.18 (error occurs by 2.14, as well). I want to clip a raster layer with a mask (shape layer) and when I do so the output is only a black layer, which is not even clipped. The CRS of both layers is the same. The raster layer has 4 bands, but the error occurs with one band as well. When i choose "Extend" the same error occurs.

Comment: Have you checked the shapefile fo geometry errors, like self-intersecting?

Comment: No, when i use the Node tool, QGIS says there are 0 validation errors.